# Cant run vagrant

Tags: terminal, vagrant, pybossa

```
default: TASK [create PYBOSSA DB] *******************************************************
default: changed: [127.0.0.1]
default: 
default: TASK [populate PYBOSSA DB] *****************************************************
default: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/vagrant/pybossa-env/bin/python /vagrant/cli.py db_create", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
default:    to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/provisioning/playbook.retry
default: 
default: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
default: 127.0.0.1                  : ok=22   changed=14   unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.